# Can Detectron2 identify human faces or not?

Tags: object-detection, face-recognition, detectron

I want to know that detectron2 can identify human faces or not.
I know detectron2 is an object detection framework so its possible or not?

Comment: Yes it can detect faces.

Comment: I mean can detectron2 identify the   I am present in the image/video or not?

Comment: mean face recognition not detection

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is also possible to detect faces with detectron2. You can either train your own model or use a pre trained model, like it is shown for example  [here](https://curiousily.com/posts/face-detection-on-custom-dataset-with-detectron2-in-python/)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.